# Page scroll to right page from menu anchor but not from direct link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

I'am using this free script

http://codyhouse.co/gem/css-faq-template/

http://codyhouse.co/demo/faq-template/index.html#payments

The demo has the same problem as my website, although it's even worse on my website.

If you use the menu, everything works fine. You have some space above the header.

[image]

But if you visit the direct link http://codyhouse.co/demo/faq-template/index.html#payments not from the menu

it looks like this

[image]

As you can see, there is no space above the header "payments".

It is even worse on my page. It starts at "Can I have.." and the header is hidden. Can not find where I can adjust this when I visit the page direct from the link without it effects how it looks when I visit the section from the menu.

When user clicks on a section

```
//select a faq section 
faqsCategories.on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var selectedHref = $(this).attr('href'),
        target= $(selectedHref);
    if( $(window).width() < MqM) {
        faqsContainer.scrollTop(0).addClass('slide-in').children('ul').removeClass('selected').end().children(selectedHref).addClass('selected');
        closeFaqsContainer.addClass('move-left');
        $('body').addClass('overlay');
    } else {
        $('body,html').animate({ 'scrollTop': target.offset().top - 69}, 200); 
    }
});
```

Javascript code: http://codyhouse.co/demo/faq-template/js/main.js

Style: http://codyhouse.co/demo/faq-template/css/style.css

Comment: I'm pretty sure the plugin is position items with jQuery and that's why clicking from the menu they line up and when using a hash in the link it doesn't line up.

Comment: yes, see my updated post with code. How can I fix that?

Comment: Firefox here, direct link doesn't show the menu at all.

Comment: @Pobe that's not a Firefox issue. Happens in all browsers with direct link.

Comment: when you use #, it's not's a javascript issue, it's the default browsers  behavior that go to the anchor link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick hack, use

```
if(window.location.hash) { 
    // if url contain '#' 
    // scroll down a few pixle
}
```

EDIT:

it's hard to demenstrated this in jsfiddle, since it won't let me play with the # hash.

```
var url = 'http://example.com/test.html#hash';  
//you can get by using window.location.href
var hash = url.split('#')[1];
// this get the 1st hash variable     

if(hash) {
// if hash exist  
    $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: "5000px"
     }, 0);
// scroll down a little bit 
}
```

Comment: How should I do that? I have tried to add padding-top to .faq-items. Padding is added but the list is still in same place from direct link.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/pwps127L

Comment: Your jsfiddle works fine and your script on my page if I reload the page. With your script, same result as before when I visit the page from a direct hash link (no extra scroll) but I if reload the page, your script takes affect and I am scrolling down a few pixels. I need to reload the page after I clicked the external hash link to arrive to the correct position. Why?

Comment: Yes in doc ready. I don't know why but if I increase the scroll speed from 0 to e.g. 200, it works fine. It's not working if the scroll speed is to low.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems there's a couple of problems here. For me it looks like everything happens when a scrolling event fire.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll();
})
```